# Why is cv2.resize() distorting my images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-resizing

I have the following image:

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkZm9.png)

I am using the following code to resize this image to 1600x1200.

```
img = cv2.imread('R.png')
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_image.resize(1600,1200)
```

I am then returned the following image:

[Final Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBGZo.png)

I have tried to fix this by using different image formats (jpg, tif), but this does not seem to help. I also tried using different interpolation algorithms like INTER_NEAREST and INTER_LINEAR, and these produce the same results.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `resize()` function on the numpy array that represents the grayscale image, which only changes the shape of the array. You should use the  `resize()` function from OpenCV:

```
img = cv2.imread('R.png')
resized_image = cv2.resize(img, (1600, 1200), interpolation = cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Besides of that, I think you have mistakenly swapped the width and height of the image, it should be 1200 x 1200 to keep the scale.